# Using Nemo, Files open behind window instead of foreground

Tags: nemo

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and every time I open a file from my "Files" from the Nemo file manager the file opens behind Nemo. When I open a file, I would like it to open in the foreground, not the background. I have poked around settings and preferences and cannot find a solution. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Install the package `gnome-shell-extension-no-annoyance`. You can use Software, but it is faster and easier with one terminal command:

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-no-annoyance`

You also will need Tweaks to turn the extension on. It is not installed by default. You can install it using the software center, or with the command line. The package is `gnome-tweaks`.

Start tweaks by searching for tweaks in the Activities screen. On the Extensions tab, you will be able to turn the extension on.